# Hide div after 5sec of registration

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

How possible is it to hide a div 5 seconds after a user registers? Here the timestamp in php of the users registration is used. I'm sure it can be done using jquery but not really certain.

I got this script online which works well for only 5 secs but it still displays after the page load and goes off after 5 secs.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">  
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#ghdiv').fadeOut('fast');
}, 5000); // <-- time in milliseconds
</script>

<div id="ghdiv">Hide after 5 seconds</div>
```

I need it to just display only once, 5 secs after a user registers

Comment: When the page loads, trigger a function that checks if the user already registered before. If so, don't show the div, else do show it. Or make the div invisible by default and have it become visible only whenthe user goes to the registration page.

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(function(){
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#ghdiv').fadeOut('fast');
}, 5000); // <-- time in milliseconds

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ghdiv">Hide after 5 seconds</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Vladu, I don't need it to show the `<div>` once, and that is 5 secs after the user registers. There is a db table that stores the datetime the user registers. 
I don't know how to add 5 secs to the datetime stored in the database    so the div shows just once

Answer (score 0):

Like this try it

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#ghdiv').fadeOut('fast');
    }, 5000); // <-- time in milliseconds
    </script>

    <div id="ghdiv">Hide after 5 seconds</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Khetesh, I don't need it to show the <div> once, and that is 5 secs after the user registers. There is a db table that stores the datetime the user registers. I don't know how to add 5 secs to the datetime stored in the database so the div shows just once